# Merge and crop multiple images on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, image, merge, crop

I have a page with the following layout of overlaying divs with images

```
    <div class="container">
        <div id="base-wrap">
            <img id="base" src="base.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="img1-wrap">
            <img id="img1" />
        </div>
        <div id="img2-wrap">
            <img id="img2" />
        </div>
        <div id="img3-wrap">
            <img id="img3" />
        </div>
        ... 
        <div id="img10-wrap">
            <img id="img10" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

The "src" attributes of #img* are set and changed with Javascript by user clicking buttons.
How can I merge all these [div>img]'s and then crop the result to get a .png file as an output (using Javasript, CSS, HTML, libraries, but not PHP).
I've drawn it below, so hope I've explained clear enough what I want.

Important thing is that "src" attributes should preserve the ability to be changed on button click. 
Thanks in advance!

[image: example]

Comment: If you're wanting a PNG as the output, you're probably looking at using HTML5's `canvas` rather than CSS; have you investigated that at all?

Comment: Yes, this is the only way to go I found so far, but before spending hours on digging into it I wanted to check if somebody has already found a better solution, because switching to canvas will also require to rewrite some code and maybe logics that I already have. But anyways I'd be very grateful for any ideas=)